# is there an equivalent to the COUNTIFS function of Excel in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have data about investments, organized by name of investor:

(firmname), company(companyname) and year of investment (roundyear).

How can I create a variable which count number of observations for each
investor (firmname) which happened in the 10 years prior to current investment?

I tried

```
bys firmname: egen exprience= count (roundyear < roundyear[_n]  & roundyear> roundyear[_n]-10 )
```

but it does not work.

I know how to do it in Excel but since the size of data is very big, it takes plenty of
time to do it.

The data look like this:

```
 firmname, companyname, year
 f1, c2, 1990
 f1, c2, 1999
 f1, c3, 1991
 f1, c3, 1992
 f1, c3, 1993
 f1, c4, 1990
 f1, c4, 1993
 f1, c4, 1994
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `egen` warns you not to make references to `_n`.

See [Stata - Moving Finite Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608369/stata-moving-finite-product) for the principle that the sum for the last so many time units is the difference between two cumulative sums.

However, I suspect that you should go straight to

http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0033

to see some technique with detailed examples.

Comment: Thank you, reading the document helped me to solve the problem, by the way thank you as well for the lesson about names.