# Countif equivalent for simple computation

Tags: sum, stata, countif

I want to do a simple Excel-eqsue COUNTIFS computation in Stata.

I have four variables
`AllCEOs Year TwoSic1 TwoSic2`. `AllCEOs` is a dummy marking valid entries (i.e. 0/1). `Year` is year. `TwoSic1` and `TwoSic2` are string variables that describe industries.

I now want to count per year how many `AllCEOs` are there in a `Year` given a specific `TwoSic?`. The step where I am struggling is that I need to count through both `TwoSic1` and `TwoSic2` as the industry ID i am summing over might be in either variable.

As far as I know, I cannot use a simple `egen = total(AllCEOs), by (TwoSic1 TwoSic2 Year)` as it does not account for the fact that  I can have the case where a value in `TwoSic2` is present in the `TwoSic1` variable and vice versa.

So far I have tried to follow advice from other threads ([is there an equivalent to the COUNTIFS function of Excel in Stata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801829/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-countifs-function-of-excel-in-stata)) but the results do not make any sense in my case.

Edit: To clarify some data and what I want to achieve. I (simply) want to count. _CountTwoSic1[row1] shall depict often the value of TwoSic1[row1] can be found in columns `TwoSic1` and `TwoSic2` for a given year. I then want to replicate this for TwoSic2 as well and sum them up in the end, but this should not be the issue.

| AllCEOs | Year | TwoSic1 | TwoSic2 | _CountTwoSic1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019 | 15 | 16 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019 | 16 | 17 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019 | 13 | 15 | 2 |
| 1 | 2019 | 13 | 15 | 2 |
| 1 | 2018 | 15 | 16 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018 | 16 | 17 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018 | 13 | 15 | 1 |

Comment: Surprising though it may seem. experienced Stata users are highly unlikely to make much use of MS Excel. So, you can't assume familiarity with a particular Excel function.

Comment: Apart from your not giving a new variable name, I would have guessed at the `egen` command you give as being an answer to your question. I miss a concrete data example making clear why you think it is not what you want. The data example can be simple and based on fake data, so long as it shows the principle of what you want.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the advice and sorry for not incorporating this right away. I have provided some clarifications above. Please let me know, should this still be ambigious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the data example, but I don't follow your hesitation. The code you suggest reproduces your desired output for the example given.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte allceos int year byte(twosic1 twosic2 _counttwosic1)
1 2019 15 16 1
1 2019 16 17 1
1 2019 13 15 2
1 2019 13 15 2
1 2018 15 16 1
1 2018 16 17 1
1 2018 13 15 1
end

bysort year twosic* : egen wanted = total(allceos)

list, sep(0)

     +--------------------------------------------------------+
     | allceos   year   twosic1   twosic2   _count~1   wanted |
     |--------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |       1   2018        13        15          1        1 |
  2. |       1   2018        15        16          1        1 |
  3. |       1   2018        16        17          1        1 |
  4. |       1   2019        13        15          2        2 |
  5. |       1   2019        13        15          2        2 |
  6. |       1   2019        15        16          1        1 |
  7. |       1   2019        16        17          1        1 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for tanking the time, Nick. The issue was in the underlying data. Your code made me realize this, thanks.